# strange htaccess query parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have searched some on this site but couldn't find a right answer to my question.

I am trying to force a www redirect and forcing an endslash on each url.

I have the following lines in my htaccess:

```
# enable rewriting
RewriteEngine on

# if not a file or folder, use index.php
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]

# force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule .? http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force endslash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

My www redirect is working fine, it will go like:

```
http://example.com 

to 

http://www.example.com
```

But now the strange part is, my end slash line is adding the url parameter which I don't want.

So this will go like:

```
http://www.example.com/path/without/endlash 

to 

http://www.example.com/index.php/?url=path/without/endslash
```

Why is it that my defined url parameter is used in this case, and how can I prevent this.

Thanks in advance

---

EDIT:

thanks to icrew

Only added no-file/no-dir before the endlash entry because otherwise it would redirect my assets.

Final code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule .? http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Well, if the requested url does not resolve to a physical file or directory then your first RewriteRule matches and does the rewriting you observe. It is what you have programmed as your first rule...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

is responsible for `http://www.example.com/index.php/?url=path/without/endslash` redirection. So basicly if you do not want url parameter in query string remove those three lines.

Edit: I figure out what you wanted. Bellow is correct code

```
# enable rewriting
RewriteEngine on

# force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule .? http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force endslash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
#next row prevent redirection if final rewriting is done
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# if not a file or folder, use index.php
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
#QSA because I suppose you dont want to discard the existing query string. Remove QSA if you want to discard
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: But my script is made so everything is handled in my index.php.
So i acually need these lines.

Can't i use both parts without having this problem ?

Comment: What do you want finall url to look like?

http://www.example.com/index.php/path/without/endslash ?